# How can I recur correctly?

Tags: java

I have a list of songs, I'm trying to produce the titles as one String
for example

```
ILo<Song> slist2 = new ConsLo<Song>(this.help,
        new ConsLo<Song>(this.hotelc, this.mtlos));
```

should produce "Help, Hotel California", but I keep getting "Help, Hotel California, "
This is my code

```
public String forCons(Song first, ILo<Song> rest) {
    if(rest.equals(null)) {
        return first.title;
    }
    return first.title + ", " + rest.accept(this);
}
```

where the method accept simply recurs the method on rest.

I also tried this

```
public String forCons(Song first, ILo<Song> rest) {
    ILo<Song> mt = new MtLo<Song>();
    if(rest.equals(mt)) {
        return first.title;
    }
    return first.title + ", " + rest.accept(this);
}


public <R> R accept(ILoVisitor<R, T> ilov) {
  return ilov.forCons(this.first, this.rest);
}
```

where

```
// A visitor for the ILo<T> classes that 
// and produces the result of the type R
interface ILoVisitor<R, T>
```

ILo represents a list of items of type T, ConsLo represents a nonempty list of   items of type T

Comment: What do your `ConsLo` and `ILo` classes do?

Comment: show us the `accept()` method.

Comment: edit your question instead of pasting code into comments, please. Also, you're using `ILoVisitor`, post this interface (and implementation, probably) too.

Comment: *"How can I recur correctly?"* - That is a very deep question.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if(rest.equals(null)) {
    return first.title;
}
```

To

```
if(rest == null ){
    return first.title;
}
```

Comment: this suggestion is ok, but OP doesn't get `NullPointerException`, so that's not the reason why his function doesn't work.

Comment: It outputs the same thing

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what are your reasons to use custom classes for data structures like lists.
What about using simple `List<Song>` from standard library?

```
int size;

public static String forCons(Song first, List<Song> rest) {
    size = rest.size();        

    if(size == 1) {     // last element
        return first.getTitle();
    }
    return first.getTitle() + ", " + forCons(rest.get(0), rest.subList(1, size));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why I didn't think of using size().